# How can i pivot this table to get it in this format?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, pivot

i have a table like the following:

[image]

how can i pivot this in pandas so that i achieve:
[image]

i would like to also add this for y3 too but due to space not added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) without values parameter and then flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='company', columns='year_active')
#alternative
#df1 = df1.set_index(['company','year_active']).unstack()
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.pivot(index='company', columns='year_active', values=['spend', 'counts', 'distinct_counts])
```

try to use this, this will work for your requirement.